# identifying miss classified values in confusion matrix in R

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I am using the caret package along with the confusionMatrix function and I would like to know if it is possible to know which are the exact values that were not clasified properly.

Here is a subset of my train data

```
train_sub <- structure(
  list(
    corr = c(
      0.629922866893549,
      0.632354159559817,
      0.656112138936032,
      0.4469719807955,
      0.598136079870775,
      0.314461239093862,
      0.379065842199838,
      0.347331370037428,
      0.310270891798492,
      0.361064451331448,
      0.335628455451358
    ),
    rdist = c(
      0.775733824285612,
      0.834148208687529,
      0.884167982488944,
      0.633989717138057,
      0.850225777237626,
      0.626197919283803,
      0.649597055761598,
      0.680382136363523,
      0.627828985862852,
      0.713674404108905,
      0.646094473468118
    ),
    CCF2 = c(
      0.634465565134314,
      0.722096802135009,
      0.792385621105087,
      0.46497582143802,
      0.739612023831014,
      0.470724554509749,
      0.505961260826622,
      0.527876803999064,
      0.461724328071479,
      0.564117580569802,
      0.490084457081904
    ),
    Wcorr = c(
      0.629,
      0.613,
      0.812,
      0.424,
      0.593,
      0.36,
      0.346,
      0.286,
      0.333,
      0.381,
      0.333
    ),
    Wcorr2 = c(
      0.735,
      0.743,
      0.802,
      0.588,
      0.691,
      0.632,
      0.61,
      0.599,
      0.599,
      0.632,
      0.613
    ),
    Wcorr3 = c(
      0.21,
      0.301,
      0.421,
      -0.052,
      0.169,
      -0.032,
      -0.042,-0.048,
      -0.035,
      0.006,
      -0.004
    ),
    Var = c("W", "W", "W", "W",
            "W", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
  ),
  row.names = c(1L, 2L,
                3L, 5L, 7L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 221L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

and here is a subset of my test data

```
test_sub <- structure(
  list(
    corr = c(
      0.636658204667785,
      0.5637857758104,
      0.540558984461647,
      0.392647603023863,
      0.561801911406989,
      0.297187412065481,
      0.278864501603015,
      0.505277007007347,
      0.403811785308709,
      0.510158398354856,
      0.459607853624603
    ),
    rdist = c(
      0.887270722679019,
      0.843656768956754,
      0.815806338767273,
      0.732093571145576,
      0.832944903081762,
      0.485497073465096,
      0.454461718498521,
      0.69094669881886,
      0.627667080657035,
      0.705558894672344,
      0.620838398507191
    ),
    CCF2 = c(
      0.802017782695131,
      0.731763898271157,
      0.689402284804853,
      0.577932997250877,
      0.715111899030751,
      0.324826043263382,
      0.298456267077388,
      0.544808216945995,
      0.458148923874818,
      0.551160266327893,
      0.461228649848996
    ),
    Wcorr = c(
      0.655,
      0.536,
      0.677,
      0.556,
      0.571,
      0.29,
      0.25,
      0.484,
      0.25,
      0.515,
      0.314
    ),
    Wcorr2 = c(
      0.779,
      0.682,
      0.734,
      0.675,
      0.736,
      0.5,
      0.529,
      0.611,
      0.555,
      0.639,
      0.572
    ),
    Wcorr3 = c(
      0.368,
      0.154,
      0.266,
      0.103,
      0.224,
      -0.204,
      -0.16,
      -0.026,
      -0.149,
      0.032,
      -0.097
    ),
    Var = c("W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
            "B")
  ),
  row.names = c(4L, 6L, 8L, 13L, 15L, 321L, 322L, 329L,
                334L, 341L, 344L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

When I use this line,

```
confusionMatrix(reference=as.factor(test$Var),data=fittedTL,mode = "everything")
```

With this I compute some machine learning using glmnet method (it gives the best accuracy ini my case)

```
classCtrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10,repeats=5,classProbs =  TRUE,savePredictions = "final")
set.seed(355)
glmnetTL <- train(Var~., train_sub, method= "glmnet",   trControl=classCtrl)
glmnetTL
```

And finally I compute the confusion matrix on my test set:

```
predict_glmnet <- predict(glmnetTL,test_sub)
predict_glmnet

CM_glmnet <- confusionMatrix(reference=as.factor(test_sub$Var),data=predict_glmnet,mode = "everything")
CM_glmnet
```

The output of the confusion matrix is a table like so

|  | B | W |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 4 | 0 |
| W | 2 | 5 |

So here I have two predictions/classifications that are not good.

Is there any way I can traceback to which row of my test set it corresponds ?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: First time I use dput, I tried to put everything for you to get the same confusion matrix as I do.